# Installshield differential installer with embedded Installshield Redistributable Object

Tags: installation, installshield

I have an installer for a product X. The installer for the product X is using an installshield object Y.

- Version 3.2R1 of product X was built with version 5.0R5 of product Y.
- Version 3.3C1 of product X is built with version 5.1R7 of product Y.

I also have a differential installer to update 3.2R1 installation to 3.3C1. It is working pretty well with normal files, but files in the installshield object Y are not updated from 5.0R5 to 5.1R7!

However, if I'm opening the differential installer with a tools from installshield, the differential installer seem to contains the version 5.1R7 of the object.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When adding an installshield object in an installshield installer, the object is given a GUID. To upgrade, I need to changed the object referenced by the installer, this generate a GUID different.

The solution is to :

- change the object
- save the project
- open the project (.ism file) with a text editor
- search for the object entry (@ism....)
- Change the corresponding GUID to be the same as the old version.

And now, the differential installer will upgrade the object!